# Importing XML into an ASP.NET Based Table:

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, visual-studio

here is the format my XML file data items takes:

```
<item context="active" type="colleagues">
<name>Colleague's Name</name>
<number>123</number>
</item>
```

However, whenever I try and use:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Container.DataItem("name") %>'>
</asp:Label>
```

I get the following error:

> System.MissingMemberException: No default member found for type 'XmlDataSourceNodeDescriptor'.`

The same problem occurs when I try and use "number" instead of "name".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by changing `<%# Container.DataItem("name") %>` to `<%#XPath("name") %>`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
DataSet xmlData = new DataSet();
xmlData.ReadXml("D:\\books.xml");
gridControl1.DataSource = xmlData.Tables[0];
```